# MySQL search by specific time period?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to select rows from table which were added in the last two hours or any amount of hours I will specify that too on the current date.

I am doing the Query like this,

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE timestamp < '2:00:00' LIMIT 1000;
```

But it is not returning any rows? Any references where I can find these kind of queries?

Comment: Juergen is close... you just want timestamp > now() - interval 2 hour... to get anything from two hours ago -- FORWARD, not everything PRIOR to 2 hours ago.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM abc 
WHERE timestamp between now() - interval 2 hour
                and now()
LIMIT 1000;
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbcf8/5)

Comment: Well it's returning the rows, but not on the current date.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a `>`? You want timestamps that were added _after_ 2 hours ago.

Comment: I guess we are getting confused here, we want timestamps that were added 2 hours ago.

Comment: Or you can say in last 2 hours.

Comment: Both @JamWaffles suggestion and yours new query seem to work for me.